# How can I set a default value to the x and y dimensions of a copied object from excel into autocad?

Tags: excel, ole, autocad, vba

I would like to set a value for the default size of the OLE object when I copy and paste a range of cells into autocad from excel.

Normally, when I copy and paste from excel into autocad, in autocad, i have to mess with the scaling to get it just right. This takes unnecessary time.

Instead, I want excel to paste this range of cells at a certain height and width. I'm curious if there are properties in excel or autocad where I can set the default x and y dimensions of the copied object.

[image: (This is the object copied into autocad) The area in blue is what i want to preset a height and width for.]

The range of cells to be copied in excel are always the same, but it just will have different data in it each job.
[image: It's the area highlighted in gray.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that on-the-fly unless you made yourself a sophisticated lisp.
For me I do all the adjustments I need on one ole object only (either scaling or aligning it to a line or a rectangle). I copy this object multiple times in the drawing then I edit these copies (OLE > OPEN) by copying the ranges I need from Excel into them.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is useful.

Comment: There's a variable in Autocad called MSOLESCALE.  I needed each ole object to be pasted with a width of 8".
I calculated a scale factor [In my case : .518] in order to get this to work. 
I then realized there is another small issue. The variable doesn't get saved in the system upon exit of autocad. This means that the variable gets set back to its default (which is 1).
The way I patched this by means of maximizing productivity was by making a button that sets .518 to the MSOLESCALE variable. Now when I hit the button, it sets the new scale on a fresh document. Hope it helps you too.